# The $N$-th derivative of a factorized polynomial

Tags: polynomials

The Rodrigues' formula for the associated Legendre function $P_l^m(x)$, where $m \geq 0$ is
$$
P_l^m(x) = \frac{(-1)^m}{2^l l!} (1-x^2)^{m/2} \frac{d^{l+m}}{dx^{l+m}}(x^2-1)^l .
$$
Now, I notice that the first few $P_l^m(x)$ have $l-m$ zeros in $(-1,1)$ (excluding $\pm 1$). I wonder if this extends to any $(l,m)$ pairs, which means that
$$
\frac{d^{l+m}}{dx^{l+m}}(x^2-1)^l
$$
is a factorizable polynomial having $l-m$ roots. If this is true, how can I show this?
In general, can we also say that
$$
\frac{d^M}{dx^M}\prod_{i=1}^N (x-x_i)
$$
with $M<N$, have $N-M$ roots?